# My IRL540N is smoking

Tags: mosfet, current, heat, heatsink

I am using an [IRL540N MOSFET](https://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irl540.pdf) to drive a 12 V pump (about 6 A) and a 12 V solenoid valve (about 1 A max). It's smoking after just two uses. I need to know two things.

1. Is it still alright? It's still working and I have switched off power. When do I know it's best to replace it?
2. How do I prevent the smoking? It's getting too hot. What's a good heat sink for such applications? I'm surprised it got so hot as it's winter and the ambient temperature is close to 12-13°C. If it's in this condition in this weather, then when summer brings 45°C it will just go nuclear. I'm scared.

Below is my schematic.

[image]

Comment: How are you driving it? How are you cooling it?

Comment: Show a schematic.

Comment: There are many reasons to heat up the IRL540N. Perhaps (1) your input control signal is not right,  (2) Yor IRL540N is fake IRF540N, (3) Not adequate heat sink, (4)  No flyback diode, etc.

Comment: One suggestion is to use a high Vgs, so Ron is small and therefore less heating up.

Comment: @tlfong01 that's good answer material, but you should probably put that in an answer, not comments. And, generally, when you say "one suggestion is", you should also say under which conditions, and why – this is engineering, not "try this and see if it still burns". "Rules of thumb" are cool, but only when they come with a set of rules that whoever applies them understands – otherwise, that's a recipe for surprise disasters.

Comment: 1kΩ between gate and driving signal (Arduino) is a bit much. I'd recommend something in the range 10Ω and 100Ω. 1kΩ could slow down the rising edge too much, which is another source of inefficiencies.

Comment: @Velvel only one switching every 15s, so that's not as critical.  it also looks like the resistor is not in between gate and gate driver, but a pull down (?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, the resistor drawn in the schematic is a pull-down. I'm referring to the resistor described in the text above the image: _"only difference being that I have connected a 1K between drive signal and gate basis a suggestion I received elsewhere"_. It would be less confusing if OP would update the schematics.

Comment: Does the Arduino output 3.3 V to the gate or 5 V? For 6 A, 3.3 V is just too low.

Comment: 1K is a bit high for a gate resistor, but it shouldn't be a problem if you're not switching at high frequencies.

Comment: PWM should be used for starting "slowly" the pump.

Comment: Why use a mosfet? sounds like what you need is a simple normally closed relee.

Comment: Please measure the actual gate voltage, as well as the voltage from drain to source when the device is ON and with a load, AND with a reasonable heat sink.

Comment: @Stian I was using a relay, but it was not connecting properly and I could hear the pump go off momentarily many times in a cycle. I might finally come back to it though. I thought MOSFET would be a neat way of doing things.

Comment: @Hearth what resistor value would you recommend for the gate resistor?

Comment: @winny 5V Arduino Nano

Comment: @Velvel Aha, ok, would go with 10 Ohm then

Comment: @DribbleNibble Something much smaller. 100 Ω or less. You can probably omit it entirely, even, if you want.

Comment: Years ago I bought a bunch of IRL540 from eBay - they were fake and had over 10x the Rds_on specified. So if your FETs are not from a reliable source, it makes sense to measure the resistance or voltage drop yourself.

Comment: 5 V should be enough, but too small margin for my comfort. eBay IRL540 means fake and higher Vgsth than stated. Get yourself a suitable transistor for the job from a reputable vendor like Digikey, Mouser, RS or similar.

Comment: tl;dr replace it ([magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) is probably already out) and then either drive the gate with 12V via another transistor (even a small BJT should be OK here), mount a proper heatsink, use a better MOSFET or do all of that at once, depending on how robust you want to be. yes, it's not an answer, because there is no "answer" here - it's hobby-level engineering, YMMV, there are no disasters, only happy accidents :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When do I know it's best to replace it?

After it smoked, it's necessary to replace it. See the "Absolute Maximum Ratings", first page of the datasheet. You've clearly exceeded that maximum temperature.

Physically, failure modes of overheated semiconductor devices involved migration of dopants, degradation of insulation, degradation of thermal coupling, … So, things you don't easily see. An IRL540N is between 1 and 2€ in single quantities – so definitely not worth risking it.

> How do I prevent the smoking? It's getting too hot.

It would seem that way, yes! So, you need to stop it from getting so hot.

> What's a good heat sink for such applications? I'm surprised it got so hot as it's winter and the ambient temperature is close to 12-13°C.

You didn't install it on a heatsink to begin with? I'm a bit surprised: The Junction-to-Ambient thermal resistance from the datasheet says 62 °C/W, so, with a loss of only 3 W, you'd be far into "beyond repair" territory.

Anyways, I'm not sure *why* you have that loss. The currents you're switching are low, and at your (starting) temperature and this current, the on-resistance should be far below 1 Ω. In fact, looking at Fig 1. from the datasheet, at 7A your Drain-Source voltage would be < 0.3V for any  reasonable Gate voltage, so you'd be converting 0.3 V · 7 A = 2.1 W into heat. Sure enough, that's a lot, but according to the datasheet thermal resistance should heat up your case to little more than 120°C hotter than ambient – not smoking hot.

So, three things are possible: you're using a gate control voltage that's too low, the current is higher than you say, or you're swithing the MOSFET on and off a lot – but these are motors, so I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want to PWM them?

In any case, when you have something that produces ~ 2W of heat, yeah, a heatsink is desirable – but a cheap one should do. All heatsinks will come with some specified thermal resistance. That, added to the thermal resistance from the MOSFET datasheet from junction to cooling surface, will tell you how hot the chip gets when you generate some defined heat power.

Comment: The current could at most be 10A, but I'm not imagining it being that much. I am controlling the gate by Arduino Nano with 1K between gate and drive for a reason I don't really understand but was told its good practice. I have updated my question, please read it. I am indeed switching the MOSFET on and off very frequently but not as frequently as it would eventually work, I'm expecting it to on/off every 15 seconds for 8-10 hours. I think I'll get a big heat sink. So just to be sure, no flashy resolution required? Just a regular aluminum heatsink would do?

Comment: ah every 15s is not "often"; I was thinking of 100 times **per** second. You're fine on the switching losses – the amount of time your MOSFET spends between "completely off" and "completely on" is negligible.

Comment: In your picture, the resistor is not in a place that makes very much sense to me

Comment: @user253751 yep, thanks

Comment: Ghe 1k resistor is a bad idea in this case. In some contexts it helps damp gate ringing. Here it reduces drive voltage by about 0% - and you need all you can get. || The FET is margional for this task. It has and Rdson (on resistance) in the 0.5 to 1v range in your application. Extreme hotness is to be expected. You has get FETs with Rdson of a few 10's of milliOhms.

Answer (score 12):

At 7A, and assuming you are supplying at least 5V Vgs (Which is where the on state resistance is specified), I make the power dissipation about 5 watts, so you will want a small heatsink to keep the thing happy, bolting it to the side of a metal case should suffic.

Note that a common trap for beginners is looking at Vgs(th) and thinking that is all the gate drive you need, when it is actually the point at which the thing just starts to conduct a tiny bit (250uA in this case), to get the mosfet hard on you need typically double whatever Vgs(th) is, details will be in the graphs.

If you try to switch this with 3.3V logic it will absolutely smoke.

There are much better mosfets for this that will run with no heatsink.

The front page of mosfet datasheets doesn't usually lie exactly, in the same sense that a government minister addressing parliament doesn't usually lie exactly...
They are however heavily influenced by marketing's desire to publish the best possible numbers, and particularly for things like maximum drain current a smart designer will go to the graphs instead.

Comment: I'm using the digital output from an Arduino Nano (I'm assuming its 5V) to drive it as I had thought being a logic level MOSFET it would be sufficient. So you are saying a 3.3V logic MOSFET would be a better choice with a Nano? Can you suggested some examples of those better mosfets you mentioned?

Comment: Well the right thing to do is to add a low side gate driver so you can hit the gate with 10V or so, but absent something like that, a IRLB8748PbF manages 6.8mR at 4.5V Vgs, so about 330mW rising to half a watt when it heats up, rather better then 3-5W of the old IRL540 (Note the 30V VDSS limit). The even more impressive MCAC130N04 manages just 2.5mR under the same conditions, reducing the heat load to just 122mW. Both are in stock at Digikey. Generally the really good stuff is SMT these days.

Comment: @DribbleNibble There's the Arduino Nano, which runs at 5 V, and the Arduino Nano 33 (BLE/IoT), which runs at 3.3 V (and has additional bluetooth or "Internet of Things" features, though that's not important here). If you have the plain Nano, it'll output 5 V, but if you have the Nano 33 it'll only output 3.3 V.

Comment: @Hearth its definitely the plain Nano working at 5V

Comment: The problem with the graphs is they are usually only "typical", not min and max. Finding mostfets that are properly specified for 3.3V gate drive is a pain. Finding them in throughole rather than SMT is basically impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see -- Look at the Id vs Vds graph, find the operating point on the Vgs and Vds calculate the power and Rds_on, etc.

Comment: @DanMills thanks for the suggestions, I think I can easily get IRLB8748 in my geography (the other I couldn't find), will go for it (with a heat sink even).

Comment: @DanMills Is IRL540's VDSS 100V better than IRLB8748PbF VDss 30V when I am placing just 12V load? is the 30V VDss going to be a problem?

Comment: At 12V either will be fine, but I didn't know your voltage. Do note that spikes and surges have to fit within that 30V limit, so you do need a clamp diode.

Answer (score 6):

Look out also for temperature coefficient of Ron. If you get a MOSFET whose Ron increases with temperature and you don't drive it hard enough on or give enough cooling, this can cause magic smoke very quickly. The Ron you see on the graph on the datasheet rises, the higher it goes the more power it tries to lose ...

Basically Ron, tempco of Ron and thermal resistance form a complex system which needs to remain in a stable state. Being conservative about calculations and generous with heatsinking goes a long way to achieving this.

[This app note](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/14692-mosfet-tutorial) gives a decent overview. In the past when I did this, I always did some prototyping, making sure to try a few different devices and measure temperature rise on the device body at maximum current (plus some error margin) - I feel that real world tests go a long way to confirming whatever paper calculations or simulations you came up with, to make sure you didn't miss anything important. This is not stuff you want to make an error with (especially in equipment which might be left running unattended, which is most equipment).

Also don't forget to be pessimistic about ambient temperature - especially if you are designing gear which might will run in a rack, with many devices all conspiring to push "local" ambient temperature up above what you expect.